# How to publish a JoyFeedbackArray Message

Tags: c++, ros, joystick

I'm trying to publish to the topic `/joy/set_feedback`.

I had this in my include:

```
#include <sensor_msgs/JoyFeedbackArray.h>
```

I had my Nodehandle and Publisher like this :

```
feed_pub = nh->advertise<sensor_msgs::JoyFeedbackArray>("/joy/set_feedback", 1);
```

Now my problem is that i want to fill up the feed_msg

`sensor_msgs::JoyFeedbackArray feed_msg;`

In the documentation [sensor_msgs/JoyFeedbackArray Message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JoyFeedbackArray.html)
it says it's an array. No matter what i did wrote there, I always get an error.

It would be very helpful if i could get a correct example to fill up this array.

I'll be needing a vibration signal with type: 1 / id: 0 / intensity: 1.0.

Comment: How you defined your callback handler?

Answer (score 0):

ROS messages can handle something like Arrays. But when you are working with a ROS Message-"Array" in Python or C++, you need to use a different data type. In your case, you need a `std::Vector<sensor_msgs::JoyFeedback>`.

For other cases, the ROS Wiki has created a table of translations between ROS Message, C++ and Python:

[image]

You can find a detailed explaination of the different datatypes and their conversion between ROS Message and Python or C++ here: http://wiki.ros.org/msg